# Using fdisk from a script

Tags: bash, scripting, fdisk

I'm creating an ISO image containing 2 partitions, from a .sh script with:

```
fdisk $image_name <<EOF
o
n



+64M
a
t
c
n




w
EOF
```

**Is there a way to do this in a cleaner way via `fdisk`, avoiding the risk of having a slight change of `fdisk` interactive tool (among distributions) breaking all the script?**

Comment: You can use `expect` to ensure you match a reply to an appropriate prompt, or you can use a different non-interactive partitioner like `parted`.

Comment: Do you really mean an *ISO* image? It is probably more correct to say *disk image*; ISO images are normally for optical media.

Comment: @meuh How would that translate into `parted` (or any non-interactive tool)? Btw which is the most used non-interactive partitioning tool? I'm using Raspbian.

Comment: You want a way to run an unknown program non-interactively and have it Do the Right Thing? Seems a large challenge. Perhaps you could check the version(s) of fdisk before launching the script, to ensure you know what you're walking in to.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using FreeBSD, then `fdisk` includes a mode (invoked with `-f`) that allows you to specify the partitioning in a configuration file.

On Linux, perhaps try `sfdisk`. Here's an example lifted from the manual page; the command:

```
sfdisk /dev/hdb << EOF
,3,L
,60,L
,19,S
,,E
,130,L
,130,L
,130,L
,,L
EOF
```

will partition `/dev/hdb` into two Linux partitions of 3 and 60 cylinders, a swap space of 19 cylinders, and an extended partition covering the rest. Inside the extended partition there are four Linux logical partitions, three of 130 cylinders and one covering the rest.

Comment: GNU `parted` would also do it, but it's more heavyweight and probably not installed by default - if that matters.